# Collapse multiple rows, keeping values of some rows in one variable and values of another row in another variable

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that reports the start and end date of contracts and looks something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(dyadID = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 13765, 13765, 13765, 13765, 43164, 43164, 43164), 
                     employeesID = c("Alf", "Alf","Alf", "Alf", "Alf", "Alf", "Alf", "Alf", "Bet", "Bet", "Bet", "Bet", "Gam", "Gam", "Gam"), 
                     employersID = c("31974", "32009", "32040", "31974", "31974", "358291", "358291", "31665", "31345", "31345", "31345", "31345", "363109", "363109", "363109"), 
                     start_date = structure(c(15613, 15863, 15937, 16295, 16299, 17037, 17045, 17136, 15692, 16097, 16141, 16513, 17116, 17554, 17913), class = "Date"), 
                     end_date = structure(c(15862, 15937, 16295, 16297, 17036, 17044, 17136, NA, 16067, 16141, 16505, NA, 17543, 17907, 18272), class = "Date")), 
                row.names = c(NA,-15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

    dyadID employeesID employersID start_date   end_date
 1:      2        Alf      31974 2012-09-30 2013-06-06
 2:      3        Alf      32009 2013-06-07 2013-08-20
 3:      4        Alf      32040 2013-08-20 2014-08-13
 4:      2        Alf      31974 2014-08-13 2014-08-15
 5:      2        Alf      31974 2014-08-17 2016-08-23
 6:      5        Alf     358291 2016-08-24 2016-08-31
 7:      5        Alf     358291 2016-09-01 2016-12-01
 8:      1        Alf      31665 2016-12-01       <NA>
 9:  13765        Bet      31345 2012-12-18 2013-12-28
10:  13765        Bet      31345 2014-01-27 2014-03-12
11:  13765        Bet      31345 2014-03-12 2015-03-11
12:  13765        Bet      31345 2015-03-19       <NA>
13:  43164        Gam     363109 2016-11-11 2018-01-12
14:  43164        Gam     363109 2018-01-23 2019-01-11
15:  43164        Gam     363109 2019-01-17 2020-01-11
```

Where employees take on multiple contracts over time.

For instance, row one shows that `Alf` signs a contract on `2012-09-30` with `employersID==31974` and that the contract ends on the `2013-06-06`. Row two shows that `Alf` signs a new contract with `employersID==32009` on the `2013-06-07`.

Sometimes the same employee signs two consecutive contracts (e.g. rows 4 and 5) with the same employer. Sometimes three or even four (in the real data up to 9) consecutive contracts (e.g. row 13-16 and 9-13).

I would like to collapse these observations where the employee signs multiple contracts in a row into a single line so that the line reports the `start_date` and the ´end_date` of this relationship.

The final dataset should look something like this:

```
    dyadID employeesID employersID start_date   end_date
 1:      2        Alf      31974 2012-09-30 2013-06-06
 2:      3        Alf      32009 2013-06-07 2013-08-20
 3:      4        Alf      32040 2013-08-20 2014-08-13
 5:      2        Alf      31974 2014-08-13 2016-08-23 # collapsed observation (one time), keeping start_date of the first collapsed observation and end_date of the last collapsed observation
 6:      5        Alf     358291 2016-08-24 2016-12-01 # collapsed one time
 7:      1        Alf      31665 2016-12-01       <NA>
 8:  13765        Bet      31345 2012-12-18       <NA> # collapsed observation (3 times),keeping start_date of the first collapsed observation and end_date of the last collapsed observation
13:  43164        Gam     363109 2016-11-11 2020-01-11 # collapsed observation (2 times),keeping start_date of the first collapsed observation and end_date of the last collapsed observation
```

With this aim I have tried the following, but it looks not very straight forward, and it does not work when I need to adjust the date multiple times

```
df <- setDT(df)[order(employeesID,start_date), same_dyd := ifelse(dyadID==lag(dyadID),1,0),
by=.(employeesID) # this identifies the observations I need to collapse
               ][is.na(same_dyd),same_dyd:=0
      ][order(employeesID,start_date), 
new_start_date:=if_else(same_dyd==1,lag(start_date),start_date)] # this creates a new variable with the correct date when there is only one new contract.
```

But this system is not efficient, it does not collapse the variables, and the `new_start_date` variable is not correct when I need to do multiple collapses.

Does anyone have suggestions to approach this issue?

thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, I edited this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by the run-length-id of 'dyadID', 'dyadID', employeesID', 'employersID', summarise by getting the `first` and `last` element of 'start_date' and 'end_date' respectively

```
library(data.table)
df[, .(start_date = first(start_date),
   end_date = last(end_date)),
     .(grp = rleid(dyadID), dyadID, employeesID, employersID)]
```

---

If we want to keep the column values from the first row of each group, create a row index with `.I` and use that to extract rows, the columns that are  not in the summary from the original data

```
out <- df[, .(start_date = first(start_date),
 end_date = last(end_date), rn = .I[1]),
   .(grp = rleid(dyadID), dyadID, employeesID, employersID)]
cbind(out, df[out$rn, setdiff(names(df), names(out)), with = FALSE])
```

Comment: Wow!!!! this is amazingly concise and efficient!!! Thanks @akrun! I would not have dreamed about something like this! would you mind elaborating a bit on the logic behind this?

Comment: @Alex There is one row that is not matching.  Is it because the `shift(start_date, type= 'lead') == end_date`

Comment: Do you mean row 7 on the original df? your are right, I did not collapse it by mistake. your output is correct. I was also wondering is there a way to use the same approach but keep also other variables in the df (that should be the same for identical dyads)?

Comment: @Alex It can be done, but I have a doubt here. which row you would want to keep here.  WIth `start_date`, we are keeping the first element and `end_date`, the `last` one

Comment: Great super useful!! Thank you very much!